# IdentityServer3 2.0.0-rc1 and vNext, how to set the CORS Policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver3

The previous method of setting it through IdentityServerOptions [has been deprecated](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/cors.html).  I have not come across any examples showing the new way.

From what I understand you can implement `ICorsPolicyService` or use one of the default implementations.  What I am not clear on is where it should be plugged in, and how to access the default implementations to configure them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparently, you can set the `AllowedCorsOrigins` through the client config and then register it with the `CorsPolicyService` like this:

```
var cors = new InMemoryCorsPolicyService(Clients.Get());
factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Services.ICorsPolicyService>(cors);
```